# PcLinuxOs demands I use only one repository at time. Is it right?

Tags: linux, debian, installer, repository

I come to your presence with this question that is paralyzing my coding efforts.

PclinuxOs was my distro of choice for reliability, but it is jealous and does not permit me to add repos from, say, Debian.

The wiki is clear advising on using just one repo, and I end up not finding what I used to find on normal Debians. Multimon, the audio decoder, for example (my other question) is not there.

When I try to install multimon with hammer and plies, it returns errors of all kinds.

Is there a way to safely and temporarily add a repository, make the install and remove the repo, returning pclinuxos to its stable state?

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix packages and repositories between different distros (with some exceptions). You can use SOME debian packages on ubuntu since ubuntu is based off debian. [PClinuxOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCLinuxOS) on the other hand is a mandriva fork, and as such there's not much of a chance (outside alien, perhaps) that you can use ubuntu debs on  - if you're lucky you can use mandriva rpms of the same version pclinuxos was forked from at the most

You could probably compile the packages yourself (checkinstall will make packages), or find someone who's compiling the packages, but no, you can't simply add debian repos to pclinuxos

Comment: Just to add my personal experience with this: on Linux, when you update AppSomething, sometimes it asks you to update Xorg, libc, EVERYTHING, then you realise some OtherApp depends on *the old version you had*, and in Linux, you can't rollback to a previous version with ease, so you can screw up tremendously just by updating packages, *especially* when they are from another distro.

Answer (score 0):

If the app isn't in the repo's make a Package Request on the forum supplying the source files and they will package it into an RPM app. Simple as that.